# avconv: converting raw mjpeg video to a viewable format

Tags: avconv

I'm using a Beaglebone Black (BBB) with a USB Webcam attached to it. The BBB is running the latest Angstrom release.

At the moment, it is proving difficult for me to convert video that I capture to some playable video format (like mp4).

My raw video is "output.raw", my command is:

```
avconv -f mjpeg -i output.raw -vcodec copy output.mp4
```

However I get an error:

```
output.raw: could not find codec parameters
```

I've tried other approaches, like using a raw YUV stream to convert but it fails on me as well.